# How to make CCMenuItemImage item with UIImage?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I want to make a CCMenuItemImage with a UIImage.  How should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make CCSprite from UIImage using this code:

```
    CCTexture2D *tex = [[[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithImage:uiImage] autorelease];
    CCSprite *sprite1 = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:tex];
```

After creating CCSprite you can make CCMenuItem using code:

```
    CCMenuItem *mnItem = [CCMenuItemSprite itemFromNormalSprite:sprite1             selectedSprite:sprite1 disabledSprite:sprite1 target:self selector:@selector(yourSelector:)];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create CCSprite to use it in CCMenuItemSprite with

```
+(id) spriteWithCGImage: (CGImageRef)image key:(NSString*)key;
```

constructor.

To get `UIImage` object has `CGImage` property, that returns `CGImageRef`.